# Как часто обновлять библиотеки python и сам интерпретатор и надо ли это?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Библиотеки часто обновляются, также как и интерпретатор python.

Надо ли их обновлять, если всё работает без сбоев и не собираешься использовать какие-либо фичи нового интерпретатора?

Comment: Есть одно прекрасное правило "работает - не трогай". А если чуть более серьезно то стоит смотреть на обновления безопасности закрывающие уязвимости. Тут все зависит от проекта.

Comment: Я вообще в итоге отказался от Anaconda и пользуюсь готовыми наборами библиотек на том же Google Colab, пусть кто-то другой следит за их совместимостью. Все мои попытки поддерживать и обновлять Anaconda кончались тем, что она ломалась и её надо было заново с нуля ставить рано или поздно.

Comment: Самая главная причина, по которой стоит обновляться — исправление багов и уязвимостей. Ещё причина — то, что мир не стоит на месте, и если вы не будете обновляться, то через какое-то время обнаружите, что все давно перешли на новые версии, ваш технологический стек уже никто не поддерживает и вы остались один сами с собой, и помощь при проблемах вам уже никто не окажет. Так что даже если работает — лучше иногда находить время для того, чтобы трогать и обновляться (но осторожно, проверяя, что обновления ничего не ломают)

Comment: Читай ченжлоги. Если там чего то на тему уязвимостей, закрытия дыр и.т.п. и твой проект может быть затронут этими дырами (к примеру если через уязвимость можно получить админ-доступ к твоему веб-проекту... сам понимаешь...). Ну, а если твоя прога оффлайн и тебе наплевать на то что ее могут изменить... Работает - не трогай. Ну и как написали выше, да, держи 2+ копии, одна работающая, в другой можешь экспериментировать как свободное время будет, пробовать обновляться и щупать как оно работает, чтобы не отставать от развития, да.

Comment: @CrazyElf с Colab проблема, что гугловцы лезут в стандартные библиотеки и правят их. Помните случай с `ntplib`, который в колабе бросался исключениями из `requests`. По мне для быстрого прототипирования Anaconda любой версии, а вот что-то сложнее уже в PyCharm с контролем обновления библиотек и тестами.